# My SpringBoot project won't load into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/angular-6-upload-get-multipartfile-spring-boot-example#I_Technologies

From the above site I have downloaded the source code for the server. It's supposed to be a SpringBoot application. However, when I try importing the files in Eclipse, it doesn't seem to recognize them.

After downloading the source code as a zip file and extracting all files in it, I have noticed that the `.project` and `.classpath` files are missing. However, when I add the two files, I just get a java application and not a SpringBoot application.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a Maven project , you have to import it as a Maven project:

> File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project

[image]

If the project is imported successfully , `.project` and `.classpath` will be generated.